# How to remove JLabels?

Tags: java, swing

Just how you add JLabels, JTextFields, JButtons by doing this add(label1); add(button1);

how to remove?

I have a button that will remove a particular JTextField.

The button:

```
thehandler3 handler3 = new thehandler3();
button3.addActionListener(handler3); // first x button

private class thehandler3 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        remove(field1);

    }}
```

It is not working. I get no compliation or execution error.

Comment: Just to be clear. Are you trying to remove JLabels after you've added them?

Comment: Yes. If the user clicks a button, it will remove the component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code would be:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint(); // sometimes needed
```

You need to remove the component and then tell the panel to layout the remaining components.

Comment: I don't have panels. My class extends JFrame. Usually instead of doing panel.add(button1);... i am doing add(button1) and it works well for me.

Comment: @razshan, you should NOT be extending a JFrame. You are not changing the behaviour of the frame. A better way to create a GUI is to use a panel to hold your components and then add the panel to the frame. Add the panel directly to the frame or set the content pane of your frame to be the custom panel. I suggest you read the Swing tutorial on "Using Top Level Container" (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) to understand this. You can also download and run the examples to see simple code on a better way to create your GUI so you don't extend JFrame.

Comment: @camickr. I have incorporated panel to hold my components. However, I have bunch of actionListeners. and In them, the program can't recognize 'frame' or 'panel'.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call remove() on the container you want to remove the component from, like this:

`panel.remove(label1);`

You will also want to consider threading issues when updating the UI:

[Event Dispathcing Thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread)

Comment: I tried doing remove(field1); (its a JTextField)..does not seems to work.  with panel.remove(field1) i get an error.